# 301 Redirect w/ Parameters IIS web.config

Tags: redirect, iis-7

I made an error in structuring my clients site such that I unnecessarily added a path that was not needed.

What I did was this:

www.mysite.com/vehicles/ford

www.mysite.com/vehicles/ford/fusion

I have since modified the site such that it now reads -

www.mysite.com/ford/

www.mysite.com/ford/fusion/

Needless to say that Google is now reporting well over 1600 bad urls, ie. 404.

I am using Godaddy shared hosting IIS, the site is done in classic ASP.

I have the web.config file figured out for the url rewrites on the second generation but am hoping to get some help with the 301 redirect. I hope I don't need 1600 redirects, but rather some code that takes anything with /vehicles/ (and after) and redirects to another page, say the home page.

Here is what I have tried but it just takes me to /vehicles/acura/